# Menu mouse-trail background effect

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

http://onioneyethemes.com/yin-and-yang/

Notice the cool mouse-over, hover effect happening above each menu item as you move your mouse over one item to the next, how it trails the mouse and then over-shoots the item slightly before returning back to rest..

What is this called?
Is it possible with JQuery?
I'd like to replicate this functionality on a site I'm busy building.
Tutorials??

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a cool implementation of the [Jquery lavalamp plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/). Notice how they have used `border-top` instead of `background`.

***UPDATE:*** Actually I'm pretty sure it's the plugin mentioned above. I checked the page source with chrome's inspect element.

Comment: I saw modernizer in the code, could be a version of that doing the same thing.. I'm not familiar with mod, hence the question about being able to do it in JQ